# SAPUI5 page with 2 containers (1 small and dynamic, 1 big and static)

Tags: sapui5

Good day,

I'm trying to create a page using SAPUI5 which basically has 2 containers.

One container is an area where the end user can select certain items on a "picture".  (e.g. different areas of a chemical plant)

The other container should then show additional information (e.g. graphs) relating to the item which has been selected in the first container.

What type of containers does SAPUI5 have which will be able to perform this function?

Comment: What do you mean by "selecting items on a picture "?

Comment: I guess a diagram would be a better word. Google 'Engineering flow diagrams' should give you an idea by what I mean with 'picture'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was you, I would select the Flexible Column Layout.
You have details here 
https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/flexible-column-layout/

More options in que left side menu (layouts or floorplans)

Working examples here
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.f.FlexibleColumnLayout

You can do 2 or 3 columns as you wish